# How do I get all results matching a GEORADIUS in redis?

Tags: redis

When executing `GEORADIUS` I can provide a `COUNT` option, but how do I specify unlimited count? That is, I want to get all results that matches my geospatial query. Worst case I can provide a ridiculously high `COUNT`, but I thought there would be some option for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, just DO NOT specify the `COUNT` option. By default, Redis returns all matching result.

```
GEORADIUS key 10 12 1000 km
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I tried leaving it out I got fewer results than when I specified `COUNT 1000`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. You might need to check if there's any bug in your code or update to the latest version of Redis. If the problem still exists, you can fire a bug to Redis community.

Comment: Even in the CLI, or maybe the CLI has a builtin limit?

Comment: My bad, looks like you are right and I did something weird.